# v-if in v-for is messing up the css

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

when i add v-if the direction switches from row to column

code:

```html
<div class="row" v-for="row in workouts" :key="row.id">
  <div v-if="row.day==1">
    <div class="post">
      <img class="img" :src="'/storage/'+row.path" alt="">
      <p class="p h5">{{row.title}} </p>
      <p class="p">{{row.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's difficult to know what the problem actually is. From what I can tell it's actually a CSS issue? Try doing `<template v-if="row.day==1">...</template>` instead of `<div v-if="row.day==1">...</div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost sure it's because you add an additionnal `div` block when using `v-if` which vertically place element.

Instead of:

```
<div class="row" v-for="row in workouts" :key="row.id">
  <div v-if="row.day==1">
    <div class="post">
      <img class="img" :src="'/storage/'+row.path" alt="">
      <p class="p h5">{{row.title}} </p>
      <p class="p">{{row.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this:

```
<div class="row" v-for="row in workouts" :key="row.id">
    <div v-if="row.day==1" class="post">
       <img class="img" :src="'/storage/'+row.path" alt="">
       <p class="p h5">{{row.title}} </p>
       <p class="p">{{row.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your CSS, this is difficult to answer.

My guess is that the extra `<div>` fails to match your CSS selectors. For example, you have something like this...

```css
.row > .post {
  /* styles for rows */
}
```

... and adding a `<div>` between `.row` and `.post` breaks it

---

The best option here is to create a computed property to filter your `day === 1` entries

```js
computed: {
  firstDayWorkouts: ({ workouts }) => workouts.filter(({ day }) => day === 1)
}
```

```html
<div class="row" v-for="row in firstDayWorkouts" :key="row.id">
  <div class="post">
    <img class="img" :src="'/storage/'+row.path" alt="">
    <p class="p h5">{{row.title}} </p>
    <p class="p">{{row.description}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i fixed it, i don't know where was the problem, i just copid the section i had below it and paste it, changed the if statement and it worked